# Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar::setFormat() must be of the type string, null given

Tags: magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool, ssh, php-7.2

When i trying to install data migration tool then getting this error in SSH

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar::setFormat() must be of
>   the type string, null given, called in
>   /var/www/html/xyz/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/App/ProgressBar/LogLevelProcessor.php
>   on line 88 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/xyz/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/ProgressBar.php:230

Answer (score 0):

I had just the same issue recently, while migrating from 1.9.1.0 to 2.3.0
The problem is that method **getProgressBar** trying to get option 
**progress_bar_format** from config.xml under your Magento1 version's folder (in my case this is /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.1.0/config.xml) to create progress bar that you can see while migration process in console.

```
/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/App/ProgressBar/LogLevelProcessor.php

protected function getProgressBar()
{
    if (null == $this->progressBar) {
        $this->progressBar = $this->progressBarFactory->create($this->getOutputInstance());
        $this->progressBar->setFormat($this->config->getOption(self::PROGRESS_BAR_FORMAT_OPTION));
    }
    return $this->progressBar;
}
```

But method *$this->config->getOption(self::PROGRESS_BAR_FORMAT_OPTION));* didn't get option and returned **null**, that's because:

```
/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Config.php

public function getOption($name)
{
    return isset($this->options[$name]) ? $this->options[$name] : null; <-- '' instead of null
}
```

So i just replaced **null** to empty strig **''**, to get default progress bar. And it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue migrating from 1.9.1.1 to 2.4.5 caused by me not specifying the config file on the command line.

```
bin/magento migrate:data /path/to/config.xml
```

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/tools/data-migration/migrate-data/overview.html

@Kirill I wouldn't recommend changing the source of /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Config.php to return an empty string instead of null when options are not set. That may have unintended consequences because every unset config option will now return an empty string instead of null. (Can't add as a comment as rep too low.)